# Show that $\mathcal{F}[\psi^{(n)}(x)] = (i\frac{p}{\hbar})^n\bar{\psi}(p)$, by integrating by parts.

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-spaces, fourier-transform

I want to show that $$\mathcal{F}[\psi^{(n)}(x)] = \left(i\frac{p}{\hbar}\right)^n\bar{\psi}(p)$$ where

$$\mathcal{F}[\psi(x)] = \bar{\psi}(p) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{i\frac{px}{\hbar}}\psi(x) dx$$

by taking:

$$\bar{\psi}(p) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{i\frac{px}{\hbar}}\psi(x) dx$$

And integrating by parts:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int^\infty_{-\infty}dxe^{i\frac{px}{\hbar}}\psi(x) = -\frac{i\hbar}{p}e^{i\frac{-px}{\hbar}}\psi(x)\bigg|^{\infty}_{-\infty} + \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dx\frac{i\hbar}{p}e^{i\frac{-px}{\hbar}}\psi^{(1)}(x) = \\ = \sum^{1}_{j=0} - \frac{i\hbar}{p}e^{i\frac{-px}{\hbar}}\psi^{(j)}(x)\bigg|^{\infty}_{-\infty} + \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dx\big(\frac{i\hbar}{p}\big)^2e^{i\frac{-px}{\hbar}}\psi^{(2)}(x)$$

If I do it $n$ times:

$$\bar{\psi}(p) = \sum^{n-1}_{j=0} - \frac{i\hbar}{p}e^{i\frac{-px}{\hbar}}\psi^{(j)}(x)\bigg|^{\infty}_{-\infty} + \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dx\big(\frac{i\hbar}{p}\big)^ne^{i\frac{-px}{\hbar}}\psi^{(n)}(x),$$

If the sum goes to zero I think I can reach the relation, but I dont know why it should go to zero, but I still have a problem with the sing of i when the $\left(\frac{i\hbar}{p}\right)^n$ goes to the left-hand side.

So I want to ask is:

> is possible to prove that relation in that way?

> if it is, which arguments should I use to say that de summation goes to zero?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: In your definition of FT $\mathcal{F}[\psi^{(n)}(x)] = \left(-i\frac{p}{\hbar}\right)^n\bar{\psi}(p)$. For example, $$\mathcal{F}[\psi^{(1)}(x)] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{i\frac{px}{\hbar}}\psi^{(1)}(x) dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{i\frac{px}{\hbar}}d(\psi(x) )$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}e^{i\frac{px}{\hbar}}\psi(x)\Big|_{-\infty}^\infty+(-i\frac{p}{\hbar})\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{i\frac{px}{\hbar}}\psi(x)dx$$

Comment: In quantum mechanics, one deals with finite wave packets (possibly large in comparison with the typical dimensions in the problem, but disappearing at infinity). Therefore, the wave function is finite and vanishes at infinity together with all its derivatives.